# How to optimize this toString() member function?

Tags: c++

I have a `Vector2D` object that returns a string representation of its current coordinates, which is called `Vector2D::toString()`. Since `Vector2D::toString()` is potentially called upon frequently, I'm wondering if there's a faster way to return a string of the coordinates.

```
string Vector2D::toString()
{
    char buffer[64];
    int length;

    sprintf_s(buffer, 64, "(%.2f, %.2f)", m_x, m_y);

    return string(buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

I feel it's doing too much work, but I could be wrong. How can this be optimized?

Updated:

```
string Vector2D::toString()
{
    static char buffer[64];
    static int length;

    length = sprintf_s(buffer, 64, "(%.2f, %.2f)", m_x, m_y);

    return string(buffer, length);
}
```

Comment: *"I feel"* and performance of C++ code do not go well together at all. If the solution above is too slow, *measure* if the alternatives are faster on your target platforms with your compiler and compiler settings. If the code is not too slow, just use the most readable and maintainable way that's fast enough.

Comment: For starters, you could use the return value of `sprintf_s` rather than doing a `strlen`.

Comment: Good point. Updated code.

Comment: It is very rare for an optimization to be worth making a function non-reentrant.

Comment: Well, I hear sprintf_s is slow due to its formatting internally, which brought up the thought anyway. It's a simple one with only two variables, so I think that's fine. Some improvements I did was make the local variables static so there's less pushing/popping on the stack, and aschepler's thought on getting the returned value of sprintf_s is one less function call. Anyway, it's better than it was. I appreciate it.

Comment: There's literally no reason for `length` to be `static`.

Comment: Why is that? I'm curious.

Comment: Because you promptly overwrite it on every call to the function without looking at it.

Comment: Without static, I believe length would be put on the stack with every call.

Comment: Yes it would for a total processing cost of 0 and RAM cost of (probably) 4 or 8 bytes. Unless this function is used in deep recursion (how deep depends on the amount of automatic storage you have) there is no need for `length` or `buffer`  to be static and a whole lot of downside.

Comment: I disagree, but value your thoughts in the conversation. I would truly care less if it wasn't an intense real-time executive.

Comment: @Phil I wouldn't assume that `length` lives on the stack. The optimizer may just hold it in a register. Look at the assembly generated by your compiler.

Comment: Take a look and see if there's anyway you can speed up allocating storage for that `string`.  It can hurt more than just about anything else you do in that function (worth it though). How do you allocate storage for and access  the array I assume backs `Vector2D`? Often lots of room for improvement there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement another version that allows a `string&` to be passed in, so that it will write to a pre-allocated string buffer instead. That prevents the `string` constructor from having to make a copy of the char buffer each time. You pay a resize penalty if the capacity is too small, but if you're repeatedly calling `toString` it should only need to actually reallocate once, after which the same `string` will have enough capacity each time.

My understanding is that std::string will generally not decrease its capacity if resize is smaller than capacity. It's technically implementation specific whether a downward resize will result in a realloc, but you could measure it yourself to verify it's behaving correctly.

Here's a sketch of what I'm thinking of, off the top of my head. Sorry if there's any errors. Feel free to remove any intermediate variables - I mostly left them there for readability.

```
void Vector2D::toString(const string& strBuffer)
{
    const int requiredCapacity = 50;
    strBuffer.resize(requiredCapacity);
    int writtenLength = sprintf_s(strBuffer.data(), requiredCapacity, "(%.2f, %.2f)", m_x, m_y);
    strBuffer.resize(writtenLength);
}
```

Example:

```
string myString;
// I'm making some guesses as to your Vector2D implementation for example purposes
Vector2D myVector(1, 0);

myVector.toString(&myString);
// myString now contains "(1, 0)" and a \0 so size() should return 7,
// capacity() should return at least 50 because of the initial resize()
// inside toString. It will probably be more because of the allocator's
// behavior.

myVector.set(1.3847, 2.3881);
myVector.toString(&myString);
// myString now contains "(1.3847, 2.3881)" and a \0, but it likely did
// not need re-allocation because it already had enough capacity from the
// first time around.
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. Good idea with passing strBuffer as a reference. However, when strBuffer is resized in the last line, writtenLength will be smaller than requiredCapacity, so I think there would be repeated resizing due to the change.

Comment: I'm impressed while measuring this with 1,000,000 cycles. The original way (on my post) took 4875ms. Doing it your way in the code above took 2484ms--literally half the time. Thanks!

Comment: If I change int writtenLength to static, it goes from 2484ms to 672ms. Wow! Very satisfied, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked so well - I hadn't even had time to test it myself! Be very careful marking things as static though - if two threads called `toString` at the same time there would be a race condition between the `sprintf_s` call and the `strBuffer.resize(writtenLength)` call, where the second thread could overwrite `writtenLength` before the first thread calls `resize`. It's better to pay the performance penalty on that. One thing you can try though - write it as one line instead. `strBuffer.resize(sprintf_s(strBuffer.data(), requiredCapacity, "(%.2f, %.2f)", m_x, m_y));` Might optimize better.